# Can I set unlimited input in C (K&R Exercise 1-16)

Tags: c

### Question regarding The C Programming Language (K&R) - Exercise 1-16

Hi, I am a beginner in C and I am reading K&R.
I have question regarding the exercise 1-16.

> Revise the main routine of the longest-line program so it will correctly print the length of arbitrarily long input lines, and as much as possible of the text.

Since we need to print "as much as possible of the text", is there any function in C can read and print unlimited input so I can compare them and print the longest one?

Here is the longest-line program in book

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXLINE 1000 /* maximum input line length */

int getline(char line[], int maxline);
void copy(char to[], char from[]);

/* print the longest input line */

main()
{
    int len; /* current line length */
    int max; /* maximum length seen so far */
    char line[MAXLINE]; /* current input line */
    char longest[MAXLINE]; /* current line saved here */

    max = 0;
    while ((len = getline(line, MAXLINE)) > 0)
        if (len > max) {
            max = len;
            copy(longest, line);
        }
    if (max > 0) /* there was a line */
        printf("%s", longest);
    return 0;
}

/* getline: read a line into s, return length */
int getline(char s[], int lim)
{
    int c, i;

    for (i = 0; i < lim - 1 && (c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n'; ++i)
        s[i] = c;
    if (c == '\n') {
        s[i] = c;
        ++i;
    }
    s[i] = '\0';
    return i;
}

/* copy: copy 'from' into 'to'; assume to is big enough */

void copy(char to[], char from[])
{
    int i;

    i = 0;
    while ((to[i] = from[i]) != '\0')
        ++i;
}
```

Comment: You can read arbitrarily long input in chunks (e.g. 1024 characters at a time) and calculate the precise length.

Comment: One option would be to change your `getline` function not to stop reading input when the buffer size `lim` is reached but to continue reading and counting characters until `EOF` or `'\n'` without storing them in the buffer. This way you could know the actual line length without limiting it to the buffer size but you will have only the part that fits into the buffer in case the line is longer.

Comment: There is a POSIX function called [getline](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html) that will read lines of any length and allocate a buffer as needed.

Comment: The PO doesn't need to save the whole line, as the problem is from chapter 1 of K&R it doesn't assume the reader has enough knowledge to print the whole line.  For unbounded lines, it is necessary to use a two pass algorithm that remember where in the file is the longest line located.  Saving the longest line in memory and printing it completely at the end is actually bounded by the amount of ram of the computer.  The original problem doesn't require to print the line completely, but only **as much as possible.**

Answer (score 1):

With the language elements you have learned in problem 1.16 of K&R it is impossible to print the longest line itself as you don't know yet how to add memory dynamically, while the program runs, to a buffer (but continue reading)

You can continue reading chars (but not copying them to the buffer) and incrementing the line length, until you receive the next `'\n'` or the `EOF` condition from `getchar()`.  This is the reason the problem says:

> ... so it will correctly print the length of arbitrarily long input lines, **and as much as possible of the text.**

A correct solution to the problem would be something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXLINE 40 /* longest line size */
/* (1)          ^^ I have changed this to test the 
 * progam with short capacity */

int getlin(char line[], int maxline);
/*  ^^^^^^ I've changed the name of this function, as
 * it clashes with the standard C function getline() */
void copy(char to[], char from[]);

/* print the longest input line */
int main()
/* I have added the type of main, as it is an anachronism
 * to still be using old legacy idioms, and it
 * eliminates a compiler warning */
{
    int len;           /* actual line length */
    int max;           /* max. length up to now. */
    char line[MAXLINE];/* actual line read */
    char longest[MAXLINE]; /* max. line stored here */

    max = 0;
    while ((len = getlin(line, MAXLINE)) >= 0)
        /* (2)                           ^^ original program
         * didn't allow to enter empty lines, as a line should
         * contain at least the '\n' but we are considering that
         * last line could have no final '\n' so we need to check
         * this way. */
        if (len > max) {
            max = len;
            copy(longest, line);
        }
    if (max > 0)    /* we got at least one line */
        printf("%d %s\n", max, longest);
        /* (3)  ^^   ^^   ^^^^ print the length of the longest line
         * and the longest line itself (we add the final \n
         * ourselves, to consider the case the \n cannot be
         * included in the line itself. */
    return 0;
}

/* getlin: read a line in s, return its length */
int getlin(char s[], int lim)
{
    int c, i;
    for (i = 0; /* i < lim-1 && */ (c = getchar()) != EOF && c!='\n'; ++i)
        /*  (4) ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ take off this test to continue
         * counting once we get to the maximal length. */
        if (i < lim - 1) /* (5) only add if we have space */
            s[i] = c;
    /* (6) c is always '\n' or EOF on arriving here, so we don't add the
     * final '\n'.  We'll print the lines with a final \n in the
     * above printf() call. ELIMINATE FROM HERE ---->
    if (c == '\n') {
        s[i] = c;
        ++i;
    } ----> ELIMINATED UNTIL HERE */
    if (i < lim-1)
        /* we need to test, as i can be > lim-1 now, we need to set
         * the last char of the string if i < lim-1 and the last
         * char of the buffer in case i >= lim-1 */
        s[i] = '\0';
    else s[lim-1] = '\0';
    if (c == EOF && i == 0)
        return -1;
        /* (7) we reached end of file, and no more data, so we return -1 */
    return i;
}

/* copy: copy 'from' into 'to'; assume that 'to' is large enough */
void copy(char to[], char from[])
{
    int i;

    i = 0;
    while ((to[i] = from[i]) != '\0')
        ++i;
}
```

Changes in the program have been marked with comments starting with a number between parenthesis, to indicate the changes.

Answer (score 0):

```
#define MAXLINE 2000000000
...
char *line    = malloc(MAXLINE); /* current input line */
char *longest = malloc(MAXLINE); /* current line saved here */
```

This pushes the limit a bit higher; now the problem is `int lim` parameter in getline.

Before it was around 1 million, probably the stack limit.

This "unlimited" is a tricky problem, and even if you use a library function (fgets, fscanf with 'm' option) there is no exact "as possible" (with a full OS).

You can even turn it around: can I read from a file until RAM is full, swap also, and other processes get killed by OOM?

I guess the exercise is thinking about buffered input i.e. reading the lines in chunks; but then where store the longest line? In a file? Using malloc? This would at least give you the chance to check if it is still "possible" to read in more of a very long line, or if you stop and keep only what is already read in. This part of too long a line would be the result -  a longer one can not be *found*.